# Inheriting methods from an other program wrote in another language

Tags: java

I'm making a system for an app, witch have for objective to allow the user to create custom script to interact with the program by handleing events and reacting to them by calling functions. The main program is wrote in java, but If want to allow the script to be wrote in JavaScript. What is the best way to do that ?

I've tryed to use the sockets to transfer data and events, but I thinks it's a bit overkill, because the app and the scripts are on the same machine. Does it exist a better way to do that?

Comment: Have a look at the graalvm javascript engine (this is a library, you don't need to run under the graal jvm)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, what you want to do is called **Remote Procedure Call** and it doesn't help much that all your code (java and js) runs on the same computer. But you can probably at least get away without authentication or security.

There are a bunch of libraries that may save you some trouble. You may want to take a look at those options:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call#General

I only got the occasion of using one: **json-rpc**, which isn't necessarily the best option, but it is the only one I can give you more details about.

The specification of the protocol is available here https://www.jsonrpc.org/specification and there should be Java and Javascript libraries to ease the implementation.

For example:

- Java - https://github.com/briandilley/jsonrpc4j
- Javascript - https://github.com/jershell/simple-jsonrpc-js

Calling this Java **hello** method:

```
public String hello(@JsonRpcParam(value="message") String message) {
        return message;
}
```

From your client, a call to **hello** would look like this:

```
var jrpc = simple_jsonrpc.connect_xhr('localhost:8080');
jrpc.call('hello', {message: 'hello world!'}).then(res => console.log(res));
```

Of course there's additional configuration, at least on sever (java) side to make this work.

Comment: Thanks, you perfectly understood what I'm wanting to do